# Splitting the Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind into real and imaginary functions

Tags: complex-numbers, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

Letting

$$K(m)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2 u}}$$

be the Complete Integral of the First Kind, is there such an identity such that

$K(z)=K(x+iy)=f(x)+ig(y)$?

Comment: There don't exist complex addition formulas for the complete elliptic integrals, that are determining the periods of elliptic functions. The question - just for fun - translates into: what is the the addition formula for a complex version of $\pi$ in the limit of $m->0$ when the elliptic $K(0)=\pi/2$ becomes the quarte period  for the trigonometric functions.